# Navbar Mobile view Links to pages not working

Tags: navbar, jquery-mobile-navbar

[Navbar Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zrY3.png) I'm not sure if i deleted code but i cant seem to figure out why my links to pages aren't working (i know basic coding so please be kind :D) (also added screenshot of what it looks like, so the links work on the desktop view but nothing happens on mobile view upon clicking)
My code for the navbar:

```html
<div class="site-mobile-menu site-navbar-target">
     <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
         <div class="website-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
             <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
 </div>   
 <header class="site-navbar py-4 js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">
     <div class="container2">
         <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col-5 col-xl-2">  
                 <h1 class="h2 site-header-logo">
                     <a href="Index.html" class="site-header-logo-image"> 
                         <imgsrc="images/Logo10Jul.png"> 
                     </a>
                 </h1>
             </div>                  
             <div class="col-12 col-md-10 d-none d-xl-block">
                 <nav class="navbar-nav site-navigation position-relative text-right" 
                  role="navigation">
                     <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                         <li><a href="Index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                         <li><a href="AboutUs.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                         <li><a href="FeltCreations.html" class="nav-link">Felt Creations</a></li>
                         <li><a href="BIBSComingSoon.html" class="nav-link">Soothers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="HowTo.html" class="nav-link">How to Order</a></li>
                         <li><a href="Contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
             </div>
             <div class="col-6 d-inline-block d-xl-none ml-md-0 py-3" style="position: relative; 
              top:3px;">
                 <a href="#" class="site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black float-right">
                     <span class="icon-menu h3"></span>
                 </a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: and is the html page with this code in the same directory like the pages you are linking to?

Comment: Yes it is, on desktop view the links work perfectly fine, its just the mobile view